# What is the probability that at least $8$ teenagers in a group of $10$ watched a rented movie at least once last week?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

> The probability that a randomly selected teenager watched a rented video at least once during a week was $0.73$. What is the probability that at least $8$ teenagers in a group of $10$ watched a rented movie at least once last week? (Round your answer to four decimal places.)

$P(X \geq 8) =$

So for this one I did

$1-{_{10}\mathsf C}_8(.73)^9(.27)^1=.2847102215$ and that rounds to $.2487$

But that is not the correct answer, can someone tell me where I went wrong and how to fix it
I also did this question with exponents as an $8$ and a $2$ but this was also wrong

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what **your** answer actually calculates.

I assume you meant
$$\binom{10}{\color{red}{9}}(0.73)^9(.27)^{10-9}$$
which is actually equal to $P(X=9)$. So under that assumption, what you have calculated is
$$1-\binom{10}{9}(0.73)^9(.27)^{10-9} = 1-P(X=9) = P(X\neq 9).$$
This is calculating the chance that $X$ is anything **but** $9$.

What you want is 
$$P(X\geq 8) = P(X = 8\cup X=9 \cup X=10) = P(X=8)+P(X=9)+P(X=10)$$
where you can just sum up the values since the events are disjoint.
Similarly, if you want to use the complement, then
$$P(X\geq 8) = 1-P(X<8) = 1-\sum_{k=0}^{7}P(X=k).$$

Comment: So (10C9) is equal to .15889532841 and then I just need to find (10C8) and (10C10) and I add those up and I will have my answer?

Comment: Please be careful. (10C9) = 10, what you gave is $P(X = 9)$. Other than that, it sounds correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(X\geq 8) = P(X = 8\cup X=9 \cup X=10) = P(X=8)+P(X=9)+P(X=10)$$

The answer is then .4664887756 which rounds to a final answer of .4665